# Boot loader chooses OS with right arrow

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, shortcut-keys, bootloader

There are several times I want to choose the last listed OS in the list, but I accidentally hit the right arrow and (to my big disappointment) it behaves just like I have clicked enter.

Is this a bug or a "feature"? Can I deactivate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho it's a feature, I always use it since it's faster (I don't have to move my fingers from the arrow keys to return). Though it's strange that it isn't mentioned in the manual, [they only write about return...](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Menu-interface)